# Как я могу получить событие нажатий кнопок обычной гарнитуры и гарнитуры Bluetooth в Android?

Tags: java, android, аудио, headset

Как отследить нажатия клавиш на Bluetooth наушниках (гарнитуре) типа: Плей/Пауза, [громкость -], [громкость +], и такой же вопрос касаемо обычных наушников, которые подключаются стандартно, через аудиовыход 3,5мм.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons  так же в документации полностью описана архитектура медиа-приложения.